# Is there an analytical solution to this equation?

Tags: analysis, summation

Let $$v_i, x ∈ R^n$$
$$ \alpha ∈ R $$
$$ d_i = \|v_i-x\| ∈ R $$
$$ f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R} $$

Consider the equation:
$$\sum_{i}\frac{f(x)}{(d_i^2+f(x)^2)^{3/2}} = \alpha $$

Is there an analytical solution for $f(x)$?

For clarity, $v_i$ is a finite set (and in my case, typically with up to 10 vectors) so this is a finite summation.

Comment: what makes you think there would be an analytical solution? Even in $\mathbb{R}^2$ you end up with something like $$(d_1^2+y^2)^{3/2} + (d_2^2+y^2)^{3/2} = \frac{\alpha}{y}$$ which hardly instills any enthusiasm...

Comment: You only have one equation for the infinite number of values of $f(x)$, so you cannot expect to find a single solution.  Sums like this are very loose constraints on a function within them.

Comment: @MorganRodgers it's a small finite summation. added clarification.

Comment: Is this from some sort of physical model?

Comment: you take care to write $f(x)$ but it seems $d_i = \|v_i - x\|$ has $x$ dependence as well? In 1D, with only 1 point, there is actually a pair of function solutions, which you can see by plotting  $y=\alpha\left(\left(v-x\right)^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}$ e.g. in Desmos

Comment: @CalvinKhor yes

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments above, in general this does *not* have an analytic solution. However, we can do a *little bit* to narrow down the form of the solution.

First of all, the $x$-dependence is a red herring. Define $y = f(x)$. Then
$$
\sum_i \frac{y}{{(d_i^2 + y^2)}^{3/2}} \;=\; \alpha\, .
$$
The quantity $y$, were one able to solve for it, would be a function of $\alpha$ and the $d_i$.

Make a change of variables $y = z / \sqrt{\alpha}$. Then this becomes
$$
\sum_i \frac{z}{{(c_i^2 + z^2)}^{3/2}} \;=\; 1\, ,\qquad\qquad (1)
$$
where $c_i = d_i \sqrt{\alpha}$. If $z = \Phi\left(\{c_i\}\right)$ is the solution of (1), then the solution to the original problem will be
$$
y \;=\; \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}} \, \Phi\left(\{d_i\, \sqrt{\alpha}\}\right)\, .
$$

This is as far as you can get in general, but at least this tells you something about how the solution scales.